# Unable to answer yes to prompt using python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, terminal, subprocess

I have been trying to get a subprocess running in python that requires me to answer a y/N prompt.

My code is as follows:

```
      process = subprocess.Popen(
        [   
            "yes",
            "|",
            "mycommand",
            "launch"
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True
     )
```

When I try to launch this Popen command, the program hangs.

When I run the same command in my Mac terminal, it runs fine:

```
yes | mycommand launch
```

What is a way that I can default yes?

Comment: Does your system have a `yes` command?  What is `mycommand`?

Comment: Normally, you would only use a list of parameters to a subprocess call with `shell=False` (which isn't even an option for you, due to the pipe in the command line).  Try it with the first parameter just being the string `"yes | mycommand launch"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash -c` or `sh -c`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd):
    result = subprocess.run([
      '/bin/bash',
      '-c',
      cmd
    ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    returncode = result.returncode
    stdout = result.stdout
    return { 'returncode' : returncode, 'stdout': stdout}


r = run_cmd('yes | head')
print(r)
```

Output:

```
{'returncode': 0, 'stdout': b'y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n'}
```

if you want to print stdout as decoded string:

```
print(r['stdout'].decode('utf-8'))
```